# Function prototype not working properly

Tags: javascript

i am a newbie to js. i was reading about prototypes and did this,

```
function person(first,last)
{
    this.firstname = first;
    this.lastname = last;

}

function SaySomething()
{

    document.write("got it from prototype");
}


person.prototype.speak = saysomething();

var nick=new person('Nick','Thayer');
document.write(nick.speak());
```

But it's saying `saysomething is undefined`
Can you tell me where i am doing it wrong.
Thanks.

**Oh My Bad. saysomething was in small. Sorry..!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the parens from your prototype assignment:

```
person.prototype.speak=SaySomething;
```

you want to define a reference to the function, not its result()

Comment: yes. If it's still doing the same, flush your browser cache? -- your example is a littel weird since document.write() returns nothing (undefiend) and then you're calling document.write() AGAIN on it. just calling nick.speak(); instead of document.write(nick.speak); or even changing SaySomething to note use document.write() at all, but just "return 'got it from prototype';"

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, it is important to note that using a function as a variable, and using the *result* of calling a function are very different.

In your code, you're setting `person.prototype.speak` equal to to the result of calling `saysomething()`, which is undefined (since it doesn't return anything).

What you want to do is refer to the function itself:

```
person.prototype.speak=saysomething;
```

Note the lack of  `()`. Now it's passing a reference to the function, instead of calling it and passing in the result.